# Spin 3/2 field in higher dimensions

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, degrees-of-freedom, supergravity, higher-spin

The Lagrangian and equation of spin 3/2 field in a general dimension D is given on page 96 of Supergravity ( textbook by Freedman and Proeyen, 2012 ). The action is :
$$ S = - \int d^Dx \bar{\psi}_{\mu} \gamma^{\mu \nu \rho} \partial _ \nu \psi _ \rho  \tag{5.2}$$
This leads to equation of motion:
$$ \gamma^{\mu \nu \rho} \partial _ \nu \psi _ \rho  = 0 \tag{5.3}$$
They claim that it works for any dimension D>= 3. But it is hard to belive for me.

When we try to find the equations for massive Rarita-Schwinger field in 4 dimensions, we do something like this:

We start with a vector-spinor field $\psi_ {\mu \alpha}$ where $\mu$ is a vector and $\alpha$ is a spinor index. Thus in 4 dimensions, we have 4x4=16 components to begin with. Then ( see the solution in the back to problem II.3.4 of Zee's QFT book ) we impose further conditions: $\gamma^\mu \psi_{\mu \alpha} = 0 $ which takes away 4 components. And then another condition $(\gamma^\mu{p_\mu} -m ) \psi = 0$ kills 4x2=8 components. This leaves us with 4 components, which is expected for a spin 3/2 field.

But the equation (5.3) is obtained just by imposing some conditions ( like Lorentz invariance, hermiticity, etc ) on the Lagrangian. It is not obvious at all that the resulting equation of motion will leave $\psi$ with just the right number of degrees of freedom. Also note that $\mu$ and $\alpha$ will take different counts in different dimensions. **So how can authors be so sure that the counting of degrees of freedom works as expected in all dimensions?**

Shouldn't one do this counting of degrees of freedom in all dimensions before trusting this Lagrangian?

Comment: Why don't you do the counting yourself to check this?

Comment: Just because it's not obvious doesn't mean someone hasn't checked it :)